# How can I make a Window Form return value of selected button

Tags: vb.net

I am making a graphical representation of a movie cinema room on a windows form. Each seat is represented as a button.

I have another button on another form that is used to book a seat. This button initiates the cinema room form and if the user clicks on any button, the text on that button should be returned and displayed.

The Cinema room class (Graphical Representation)

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Cinema1Seats
    Dim seat As String = vbNull
    Private Sub Cinema1Seats_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try

        con = getconnect()
        con.Open()
        Dim comm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        comm = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from seats ", con)
        ' comm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ticketNumber
        Dim sqlReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        sqlReader = comm.ExecuteReader
        Do While sqlReader.Read
            Dim seat As String = sqlReader.GetString(0)
            Dim seatbtn As New Button
            seatbtn.Width = 50
            seatbtn.Height = 20
            seatbtn.Text = seat


            AddHandler seatbtn.Click, AddressOf Me.Button_Click   ' Again from answer by Reed.
            Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(seatbtn)
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try





End Sub
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim asas As String = (CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button).Text)
    MsgBox(asas)
End Sub
Public Function getseat() As String
    If (seat = vbNull) Then

    Else
        Return seat
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Function


End Class
```

The Second form which has the button

```
Public Class SampleSeat_vb

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try
        Dim flag As Integer = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < Application.OpenForms.Count And flag = 0
            If Application.OpenForms(i).Name = "Cinema1Seats" Then
                flag = 1
            End If
            i += 1
        End While
        If flag Then
            Application.OpenForms("Cinema1Seats").BringToFront()
        Else
            Dim str As New Cinema1Seats
            str.Show()
            Dim we As String = str.getseat
            MsgBox("You selected : " + we)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try





End Sub

Private Sub SampleSeat_vb_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Adding a method named "get_seat" to a class that represents a collection of seats does not make sense.  You can't write proper code if the design is not correct.  If you want to know what seat was clicked last then you need a variable.  Assign it in the Click event handler.

Comment: the oddly named variable `asas` simply needs a different `Scope`.  Make it a property of `Cinema1Seats`.

Comment: Sorry about the varaible Plutonix,  @Hans Thanks for the Help. I thought of 'asas' but now I know I've messed everyone up. How can I make the form with seats as buttons run as a jOptionPane in Java such that when I click button on bookingform to select seat, the seatsform pops up, user clicks on a button, the button text or tag is saved in a variable X, seatsform is closed and I continue execution with the variable X as I wish in bookingform. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not enitrely clear to me what you are trying to achieve but in order to find the text of the button that was clicked you can do something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked on " + btn.Text")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, Sorry my question is not a not clear and i'm not familiar with VB.NET, Your answer shows a message if a button on a form if clicked and that is fine. But What I want you to help me with this, imagine having two forms form1 and form2, you have a button on form1 that executes some code and while executing it has to get seat number x, then form2 is launched and it has a number of buttons, when the user clicks any button on form2, form2 is closed and value x is the value of CType(sender, Button). I the form to act as a jOptionPane in JAVA. Thanks